# registrar datos en tablas distintas

Tags: php, mysql

me surge la siguiente duda: tengo en mi base de datos tres tablas (estudiante(rol 1), profesor(rol 2), acudiente (rol 3)) cada uno de ellos tiene un rol especifico y tengo un formulario para registrar los datos, quisiera saber si hay una forma de registrar el dato en una tabla especifica cuando inserte el rol, por ejemplo si en mi formulario selecciono el rol 1 me guarde el registro en la tabla estudiantes, si selecciono el rol 2 me guarde el registro en la tabla profesor etc..

en este codigo me registra pero solo en la tabla que yo especifico (estudiantes)

```
$trol = $_POST["trol"];<br>
$tnombres = $_POST["tnombres"];<br>
$tapellidos = $_POST["tapellidos"];<br>
$tcorreo = $_POST["tcorreo"];<br>
$tcelular = $_POST["tcelular"];<br>
$tdireccion = $_POST["tdireccion"];<br>
$tnombres = $_POST["tnombres"];


$buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name
WHERE id_estudiante = '$_POST[tusuario]' ";

$result = $conexion->query($buscarUsuario);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
echo "<br />". "El Nombre de Usuario ya a sido tomado." . "<br />";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Por favor escoga otro Nombre</a>";
}<br>
else{<br>
$query = "INSERT INTO estudiantes (id_estudiante, nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, direccion, id_rol, contrasena)
           VALUES ('$_POST[tusuario]', '$tnombres', '$tapellidos', '$tcorreo', '$tcelular', '$tdireccion', '$trol', '$hash')";<br>
 }
```

espero me halla hecho entender, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría ser agregando un switch para generar el query dependiendo el rol

```
$query="";
switch($trol)
{
  case 1:
    $query="insert into Estudiante() values()";
  break;
  case 2:
     $query="insert into Profesor() values()";
  break;
  case 3:
     $query="insert into Acudiente() values()";
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando un poco los campos para efectos de una respuesta más compacta, digamos que tus tablas tienen campos `correo` y `nombres` además de la llave primaria que es autoincremental y no necesitas insertarla explícitamente. Dicho esto, Tienes tres problemas:

1. No estás comprobando si vienen todos los campos. Puede que intentes buscar en $_POST una llave que no se envió.
2. Asumes que de antemano la persona que quiere registrarse conoce su ID. Si la persona no existe en la BBDD no tiene ID, ¿Cómo podría adivinarlo el usuario?
3. Tu lógica tiene fallas de seguridad, porque estás interpolando lo que te pasan por POST directo en tus sentencias.

**Para el punto 1**, debieras envolver todo en una comprobación:

```
if(!isset($_POST["trol"],$_POST["tcorreo"],$_POST["tnombres"])) {
  echo "<br />". "No ha enviado todos los campos." . "<br />";
  echo "<a href='index.html'>Por favor complete todos los campos</a>";
} else {
  // tu lógica acá
}
```

**Para el punto 2**, debieras usar otro campo (como el correo) para saber si el usuario ya existe

**Para el punto 3**, lo primero sería castear `$_POST['trol']` a un entero y luego ver si existe el rol entre tu diccionario `rol => tabla`

```
$diccionario = [
 1 => 'estudiante',
 2 => 'profesor',
 3 => 'acudiente'
];

$trol = (int) $_POST['trol'];

if(!array_key_exists($trol, $diccionario)) {
   echo "<br />". "Ese rol no existe en el sistema." . "<br />";
   echo "<a href='index.html'>Por favor escoja otro rol</a>";
} else {
  // tu lógica
}
```

Cuando lo casteas te aseguras de no insertar en la tabla un string arbitrario que podría prestarse para una inyección SQL. Si el rol existe en el diccionario puedes obtener de él el nombre de la tabla, que inevitablemente vas a interpolar en tus sentencias. Pero al menos tú manejas el diccionario así que esa interpolación es inofensiva.

Hechas las comprobaciones, ya puedes hacer:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$correo = $_POST['tcorreo'];
$nombres = $_POST['tnombres'];
$tabla = $diccionario[$trol];

$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT correo from $tabla WHERE correo=?");
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $correo);

$stmt1->execute();

$stmt1->store_result();
$count = $stmt1->num_rows;
$stmt1->close();

if($count > 0) {
   echo "<br />". "El email de Usuario ya ha sido tomado." . "<br />";
   echo "<a href='index.html'>Por favor escoga otro email</a>";
} else {

  // lógica de inserción

}
```

Entonces llegamos al punto en que comprobaste que:

- El rol existe en tu diccionario
- Los campos fueron poblados en el formulario
- El email está libre en la tabla que obtienes del diccionario

Así que aplicas la inserción:

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (correo, nombres) VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt2->bind_param("ss", $correo, $nombres);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->close();
```

Poniendo todo junto y reordenando para no tener tantos if anidados:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$diccionario = [
    1 => 'estudiante',
    2 => 'profesor',
    3 => 'acudiente',
];

$trol = isset($_POST['trol']) ? (int) $_POST['trol'] : 0;

if (!array_key_exists($trol, $diccionario)) {
    echo "<br />" . "Ese rol no existe en el sistema." . "<br />";
    echo "<a href='index.html'>Por favor escoja otro rol</a>";
} else if (!isset($_POST["trol"], $_POST["tcorreo"], $_POST["tnombres"])) {
    echo "<br />" . "No ha enviado todos los campos." . "<br />";
    echo "<a href='index.html'>Por favor complete todos los campos</a>";
} else {
    $correo = $_POST['tcorreo'];
    $nombres = $_POST['tnombres'];
    $tabla = $diccionario[$trol];

    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT correo from $tabla WHERE correo=?");
    $stmt1->bind_param("s", $correo);

    $stmt1->execute();

    $stmt1->store_result();
    $count = $stmt1->num_rows;
    $stmt1->close();

    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "<br />" . "El email de Usuario ya ha sido tomado." . "<br />";
        echo "<a href='index.html'>Por favor escoga otro email</a>";
    } else {

        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (correo, nombres) VALUES (?, ?)");

        $stmt2->bind_param("ss", $correo, $nombres);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->close();

        echo "<br />" . "Todo funcionó: Usuario creado en la tabla $table." . "<br />";
    }

}
```

A este script le faltan comprobaciones para manejar los casos en que no logras conectarte o los statements se ejecutan mal, pero eso te queda de tarea.